# How to build signed grubx64.efi for grub2?

Tags: linux-mint, compiling, grub2, uefi

I can build a 64-bit efi grub2 boot file using `grub-mkimage` under Linux-Mint.
But I want to make one that I can use with the signed shim

bootx64.efi  - signed shim (e.g. from Ubuntu)

grubx64.efi  - grub2 (e.g. from Ubuntu)

This boots in Secure Boot mode OK. But if I substitute the `grubx64.efi` file for the one I build, it only boots in non-Secure-boot mode.

The `grub-mkimage` script seems to have a provision for a public key. Is this what I need to add. If so, where do I get the key from and how do I add it?

Comment: I forgot to add, I want this for USB booting which uses bootx64.efi as a default boot file.

Answer (score 2):

The public key that is embeddable using the `-m` option of `grub-mkimage` is for signing any files GRUB will read. This uses GPG-style detached signature files (`*.sig`). But it has nothing to do with Secure Boot as such.

For Secure Boot signing, a different kind of signature is needed. A Secure Boot-compatible signature is embedded in a PE32+ binary file itself. There are at least three tools that can make such a signature:

- `sbsign` from [sbsigntools by Jeremy Kerr/Ubuntu](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jejb/sbsigntools.git)
- `pesign` by [Peter Jones/RedHat](https://github.com/rhboot/pesign).
- `osslsigncode` by [Michał Trojnara](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode)

You'll need to have your shim configured to use a MOK (Machine Owner's Key). You can do this using `mokutil`, or Debian/Ubuntu-related distributions may offer a more beginner-friendly `update-secureboot-policy` script to do the job. If you use it, you'll find the MOK certificate (in DER format) and the corresponding private key in `/var/lib/shim-signed/mok`.

The signing tools `sbsign` and `osslsigncode` will require the MOK certificate in PEM format. The private key will already be in PEM format. The certificate conversion is simple:

```
sudo openssl x509 -inform DER -in /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der -outform PEM -out ~/MOK_certificate.pem
```

The `pesign` tool will require the MOK stored in NSS-style certificate database. You can use `openssl pkcs12 -export` to first convert the certificate and private key into a single PKCS#12 file, and then `pk12util` to import that file into a new NSS certificate database directory (a directory with three files in it: `cert8.db`, `key3.db` and `secmod.db`).

Then you would use one of the above-mentioned tools to sign the `grubx64.efi` using your MOK certificate and its corresponding private key:

```
sbsign --key <MOK private key file.pem> --cert <MOK certificate.pem> --output grubx64.efi.signed grubx64.efi
# or
pesign --in=grubx64.efi --out=grubx64.efi.signed -c <name of certificate in NSS certificate store> -n <NSS certificate store directory> -s
# or
osslsigncode -certs <MOK certificate.pem> -key <MOK private key file.pem> -h sha256 -in grubx64.efi -out grubx64.efi.signed
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the key that was embedded into shim, most likely this means the access to build service (maybe with some privileges) -- ask grub package maintainer.  I've noted some details [here](http://en.altlinux.org/UEFI_SecureBoot_mini-HOWTO) while messing with all of that back then...